# Stack Overflow Careers acting like creepy stalker

Tags: discussion, jobs, email

While I acknowledge and appreciate the initiative involved in scanning a users GitHub page for new repos, the followup email "inviting" me to update my SOC profile to reflect the new repo ends up reading more like a creepy stalker.

Comment: [For your viewing pleasure](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/23648588.jpg)

Comment: The simile here, while humorous, is annoying and counts as one strike against Careers. The question remaining is whether there are 2 or 3 strikes per out in this game.

Comment: @gobernador: I'm seriously creeped out right now.

Answer (score 22):

Update: We no longer send this email at all!

---

We're going to tweak the email to not be so...stalkerish.

We do prefer (and users have responded positively to date) the personalized calls to update your profile. If you receive one, you won't receive the more generic nudge email we send out every three months.

Comment: For those unaware, Will is the product manager for Careers 2.0.

Answer (score 20):

Just to make sure this gets a post of its own because it is awesome. All credit to [gobernador](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181088/gobernador)

[image]

Meme in question is ["Overly Attached Girlfriend"](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/overly-attached-girlfriend).

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qXdgpmgaNg http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9zOeLRmGVA&feature=related